# Draw table in C — like table on manual page of Linux

Tags: c, linux, formatting

I want to make nice tables like you see on some manual page of Linux documentation
in C programming language.  Is there any library or functions to create a table like them.
For example a table that you can find on man syslog like the following, produced by running `man syslog`:

```
   ┌──────────────────────┬───────────────┬────────────────────┐
   │Interface             │ Attribute     │ Value              │
   ├──────────────────────┼───────────────┼────────────────────┤
   │openlog(), closelog() │ Thread safety │ MT-Safe            │
   ├──────────────────────┼───────────────┼────────────────────┤
   │syslog(), vsyslog()   │ Thread safety │ MT-Safe env locale │
   └──────────────────────┴───────────────┴────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the ncurses library here: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/

Comment: Definitely what to use if you want to see this in a terminal program.

Answer (score 2):

This was probably done with "tbl". See `man tbl`. Also see the L. L. Cherry
 and M. E. Lesk document "Tbl — A Program to Format Tables" which can be found via Google.

An example

This file:

```
$ cat f.tbl
.TS
allbox;
c s s
c c c
n n n.
AT&T Common Stock
Year    Price   Dividend
1984    15-20   $1.20
5   19-25   1.20
6   21-28   1.20
7   20-36   1.20
8   24-30   1.20
9   29-37   .30*
.TE

* (first quarter only)
```

Produced this (with `tbl f.tbl > f.troff; nroff f.troff`):

```
┌────────────────────────┐
│   AT&T Common Stock    │
├─────┬───────┬──────────┤
│Year │ Price │ Dividend │
├─────┼───────┼──────────┤
│1984 │ 15‐20 │  $1.20   │
├─────┼───────┼──────────┤
│   5 │ 19‐25 │   1.20   │
├─────┼───────┼──────────┤
│   6 │ 21‐28 │   1.20   │
├─────┼───────┼──────────┤
│   7 │ 20‐36 │   1.20   │
├─────┼───────┼──────────┤
│   8 │ 24‐30 │   1.20   │
├─────┼───────┼──────────┤
│   9 │ 29‐37 │    .30*  │
└─────┴───────┴──────────┘
* (first quarter only)
```